# zf2 website with a single entry-point, no routes/paths in URL

Tags: zend-framework2

Is it be possible to make a website that doesn't reveal any relative URL's at all?
Say for example, I have a domain name "somedomain.xyz" and I want to route everything through the default route, and I want not to reveal any paths or route structures to the end user.
The end user shall only see the domain name in the browser's address bar, like:

```
     http://somedomain.xyz
```

or

```
    https://somedomain.xyz.
```

Any path like

```
  http://somedomain.xyz/index.php
```

or

```
   http://somedomain.xyz/index or 
   http://somedomain.xyz/index/index
```

shall show a 404.
And I don't care about SEO stuff and static pages.
Is that possible with ZF2, and if yes, then how?

similar question: [hide module and action name from zf2 routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510300/hide-module-and-action-name-from-zf2-routing?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a hostname route for `subdomain.xyz` like so:

```
'my-route' => array(
    'type' => 'Hostname',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => 'subdomain.xyz',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'MyApp\Controller\TheController',
            'action'     => 'whatever-action',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: thanks! :) see also here for a complete solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165223/zf2-routing-via-post-vars

Answer (score 0):

see here for a complete solution, with using HTTP POST vars for the routing:
[ZF2 routing via post vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165223/zf2-routing-via-post-vars)